# Javascript for AlphaNumeric and Uppercase typing

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have coded javascript for AlphaNumeric. Also if user type lower case then it convert into uppercase. Converting from lower case to upper case `obj.value = String.fromCharCode(key).toUppercase();` not working properply. Please help me to sort out it. Thanks in advance..

```
function isAlphaNumeric(e, obj, index) {
     var key;
     if (window.event) {
         key = window.event.keyCode; //IE
         obj.value = String.fromCharCode(key).toUpperCase();
     } else {
         key = e.which; //firefox
         obj.value = String.fromCharCode(key).toUpperCase();
     }
     if (!((key > 64 && key <= 90) || (key > 96 && key <= 122) || (key > 47 && key <= 57) || (key == 8) || (key == 0) || (key == 127))) {
         alert(" Enter only Alpha-Numeric value in this field. ");
         setTimeout(function () {
             clearField(obj)
         }, 500);
         return false;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mate check out my answer:

```
   $('textarea').bind('keydown keypress keyup', function (e) {
       var replacedText = $(this).val().replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/g, function (match) {
           if (match != undefined) {
               return match.toUpperCase();
           }
       });
       $(this).val(replacedText);
   });
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v8db8/1/)

Comment: Last character not changing into uppercase.. Please look at the demo.

Comment: @siva did you check it out ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use .toUpperCase() instead of .toUppercase() as Javascript is case sensitive.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp

Comment: Sorry that was typo mistake.. In code i used toUpperCase() only.